Why aren't there good large language models that have a small token count?
There are many examples where language models can’t count letters in a word. I would assume this also means they cannot count syllables or figure out rhythmic properties of written text.
These seem like serious limits where inventing a new word or just rhyming with constraints will hardly work.
I assume the context length is a big limitation and a reason for such a big token count in the mainstream models but as far as I know there’s been a lot of work to extend the context to large lengths where having a hundred tokens might work.
Why aren't there good large language models that have a small token count?

small token count = ?

A token in popular language models represents around 4 characters. Why wouldn't it represent just 1 character? Because this would require bigger contexts.
I assume this is not the place to ask the question then, as it is a technical question. I should ask it in machine learning.
small token count = small token dictionary

You can use one of the mainstream GPT-4o versions for that. Just split words to encourage GPT to use short tokens. Like this:
system:
Y o u   a r e   a   h e l p f u l   a s s i s t a n t .
Y o u   w r i t e   o n e   c h a r a c t e r   a t   t i m e   a n d   s e p a r a t e   w o r d s   w i t h   3   s p a c e s .

user:
I n v e n t   a   c r a z y   n a m e   f o r   a   c l o t h i n g   b r a n d  
 w i t h   a   d r a g o n   i n   l o g o . 

However, have in mind that default filtering from chatGPT is going to block this kind of prompt because it recognizes it as a jailbreak attempt. To run the above prompt in Azure OpenAI, I needed to disable the jailbreak filtering. (I created a custom content filter without jailbreak protection and attached it to my model deployment.)
You can use this python code to add spaces to user input:
'hello world' -> 'h e l l o   w o r l d '
' '.join(text)

And this python code to remove extra spaces from bot answer:
'h e l l o   w o r l d ' -> 'hello world'
' '.join([''.join(x.split(' ')) for x in text.split(' ' * 3)])

Examples
These are examples of conversations I had using the system prompt above:
user:
replace 3 random vowels with "u" in word "international"

assistant:
inturnutionul

user:
Invent a new word for a name of death metal band 
that has demonic appearance and the vocalist who loves cute cats. 
Give 5 proposals.

assistant:
1.Cataclaws 2.Satanpaws 3.Demonipurr 4.Felinomania 5.Hellkitty

user:
invent a word starting with "b" as a fake adjective describing a funny person

assistant:
banterly

user:
count letters "a" in "amazing idea"

assistant:
3



Why aren’t there good large language models that have a small token count?

The "token count" is called vocabulary size. Some papers looked at vocabulary size vs. LLM perf, e.g.:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2310.08754:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2406.16508:


Why wouldn't it represent just 1 character?

That'd render the embeddings virtually meaningless, since 1 character typically has tons of different contexts (except for logographic scripts).

I think I’m starting to understand. There’s no positional awareness of the character in an LLM. I guess it’s then extremely limited and does not actually model certain properties associated with spoken language and cannot even model it if we used phonemic orthography.
